# Using real date partitions with MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, partitioning

We are currently using MySQL 5.5, coming from MySQL 5.1. In 5.1, all you can do to create partitions by date is to use the to_days() function. However, it seems that in MySQL 5.5, you can [use dates directly without this workaround](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_55_partitioning.html).

What this article fails to mention is if there is a way from the workaround way to the new way. How could I migrate from using to_days() to no longer using to_days()?

Answer (score 0):

To change partitioning type use `ALTER TABLE ... PARTITION BY ...` with new partitions' definition. See [18.3.1. Management of RANGE and LIST Partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-management-range-list.html)

You cannot use REORGANIZE PARTITION to change the table's partitioning type; that is, you cannot (for example) change RANGE partitions to HASH partitions or vice versa. You also cannot use this command to change the partitioning expression or column. To accomplish either of these tasks without dropping and re-creating the table, you can use ALTER TABLE ... PARTITION BY .... For example:

So follow the example you refer to, but change `CREATE TABLE` to `ALTER TABLE`

```
ALTER TABLE Annual_Data
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS (date_field)
 (
  PARTITION p01 VALUES LESS THAN ('2007-01-01'),
  PARTITION p02 VALUES LESS THAN ('2008-01-01'),
  PARTITION p03 VALUES LESS THAN ('2009-01-01'),
  PARTITION p04 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE));
```